# $A = \{a\in \mathbb{R}:h(a)=2\}$. Suppose $(a_n)$ is contained in $A$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$, prove $a$ is in $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$h:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A = \{a\in  \mathbb{R}:h(a)=2\}$. Suppose $(a_n)$ is contained in $A$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}=a$, prove $a$ is in $A$.

I have no idea how to prove this type of question, anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: $\lim h(a_n) = h(\lim a_n)$

Comment: @Jakoer : Please look at my edits to your question.  There is no reason to put the $\{$curly braces$\}$ _outside_ of the math tags, and doing so causes mismatches in fonts sizes and imperfect spacing.  And $a\in\mathbb R$ can be written, rather than $a\ in\ \mathbb R$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions preserve limits in sequences,    So, since $a_n\to a$,  you have $h(a_n)\to h(a)$.  But since each $a_n\in A$, we have $h(a_n)=2$ for each $a_n$, so you have a constant sequence. A constant sequence converges to itself, hence $h(a)=2$,  hence by definition, $a\in A$

Comment: I don't think I could just say it is a constant sequence here.

Comment: every single term in the new sequence $h(a_n)$ is identically equal to 2, so it is a sequence of constant terms, all 2.